# Где ошибка? Говорят, что что-то с граматикой не так

Tags: грамотная-речь

Гордимся нашим коллегой из "Название компании"! 
Дмитрий из дочерней компании "Название" первый, кто добрался своим ходом на мотоцикле до столицы Ло Мантанг королевства Мустанг! Оно до 1991 года было закрытым для туристов. Он преодолел более 500 км бездорожья, перевалы на высоте до 5000 тысяч метров, броды, снег, туман и палящее солнце. Цифровизация добралась в самые отдаленные уголки планеты.

Answer (score 0):

Гордимся нашим коллегой из "Название компании"! Дмитрий, из дочерней компании "Название",  первый, кто добрался своим ходом на мотоцикле до столицы Ло Мантанг королевства Мустанг, которое до 1991 года являлось закрытым для туристов. Он преодолел более 500 км бездорожья, перевалы на высоте до 5000 тысяч метров, броды, снегопады, туман и поход под палящим солнцем.  Цифровизация добралась в самые отдаленные уголки планеты.

Comment: Предложение о цифровизации вообще удалить, оно не связано по смыслу с предыдущим текстом.

Answer (score 0):

Гордимся нашим коллегой из "Название компании"! Дмитрий из дочерней компании "Название" -  первый, кто добрался своим ходом на мотоцикле до столицы Ло Мантанг королевства Мустанг! Оно до 1991 года было закрытым для туристов. Он преодолел более 500 км бездорожья, перевалы на высоте до 5000 тысяч метров, броды, снег, туман и палящее солнце: цифровизация добралась в самые отдаленные уголки планеты!